# How to override global functions in JavaScript, but keep a reference to the original function?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to implement a custom function for window.confirm, so I don't have to rewrite a large amount of legacy code, but be able to fallback to the original function if something goes wrong, or depending on some arbitrary logic.

A quick stub code, just for example (probably won't do it like this, but just for an idea):

```
window.confirm = function(message, successCallback){
  var ok = site.UI.confirmDialog(message);
  if (ok && typeof(successCallback) == 'function'){
      successCallback();
  } else {
     // maybe call original browser confirm?
     // window.confirmOriginal...?
  }
}
```

The question here is, how to get the original function if I'm overwriting it? Does it exist somewhere on the prototype, or am I looking at this all the wrong way?

Thanks.

Comment: I would ***strongly*** advise you not to override `confirm` with something that behaves *differently* from `confirm` (doing a callback rather than blocking). Create a function with a different name.

Comment: Re the `inheritance` tag: This has nothing to do with inheritance. I've removed the tag.

Comment: I was really curious if the original function existed somewhere, without having to explicitly store a reference - I get a lot of how JS works, but still exploring subtleties :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dtfuj/)

```
var origConfirm = window.confirm; //store for future use

​window.confirm = function(msg){   //override
     alert(msg);   
}

window.confirm('override!');      //should now be an alert
origConfirm('old confirm');       //the old confirm
```

Comment: Won't origConfirm pick up the new function, when I overwrite?

Comment: @danp: No, it won't. For the same reason that in `a = new Date(); b = a; a = new Date();`, `b` refers to the first date created, not the second. Functions are just objects in JavaScript.

Comment: Hm, yep - just tried and it works. However, I understood, that when you do a = {key:'thing'}; a = b; then anything you change in a will also be reflected in b? I get that functions are objects.

Comment: @danp: *"However, I understood, that when you do `a = {key:'thing'};` `a = b;` then anything you change in `a` will also be reflected in `b`?"* When you do that, `a` and `b` both refer to the same object. So if you change the object in some way, you'll see that change whether you're looking through the `a` reference or the `b` reference. But that's a totally different situation than assigning something *different* to `a` -- changing `a`, not what it refers to -- as we are here.

Comment: The function is a brand new object, and nothing to do with the original window.confirm code. yep?

Comment: When you override functions like this, it's also a good idea to call them with the same context that they should have had before `origConfirm.apply(window, arguments)` Not bulletproof, though, because the context can be bound to whatever the author decides. Pure functions avoid this all together.